# How to pass arguments by reference when call python in c++ with pybind11

Tags: python, c++, lifetime, pybind11, cross-language

I'm using **PyBind11** to run a Python interpreter, and I need to call a Python function in c++ with some pointer arguments.

According to the docs of pybind11, it looks like that a argument being passed to Python side should be freed normally by the Python interpreter, instead of the c++ main program.
But this time the argument is a pointer to a static object, it should **NOT** be freed by anyone. How to code such a binding/calling?

I know that `pybind11::return_value_policy::reference` can be used to prevent a returning result from being freed, but it is for a returning object, not for arguments.

Any hint will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can define a python wrapper inside [an embedded module](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/embedding.html#adding-embedded-modules) and access it from inside the python code. Then you can specify an appropriate return value policy when defining the getter, like this:

```cpp
extern MyObject global_object;

PYBIND11_EMBEDDED_MODULE(statics, m) {
  m.def(
    "global_object",
    []() -> MyObject& {
      return global_object;
    },
    pybind11::return_value_policy::reference
  );
}
```

Then either call the `statics.global_object()` directly from the python code, or, if you still want to use pass it as an argument from C++, call the `statics.global_object()` in the interpreter and store the result in C++ as a `py::object` which you can then pass as an argument.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a bit?

Comment: I tried to clarify this a bit, hope it helps :)